# Android SphericalUtil.computeOffset with 90 degrees returns point with wrong latitude

Tags: android, maps

I'm using SphericalUtil.computeOffset, which takes 3 params

```
 public static LatLng computeOffset(LatLng from, double distance, double heading)
```

in this way:

```
LatLng position = new LatLng(50, 14);
double distance = 2 * 1000 * 1000 //2 thousand kilometers
LatLng result = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(position, distance, 90);
```

and I expect that resulting point will have same latitude, because I pass 90 degrees, which "strictly to the East" direction, but in real it returns point with

(46.76979930677399,40.79730389984821)

coordinates.

If i use less distance it will be closer to origin, if bigger - it becomes even worse

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I'm passing wrong angle?

Comment: Sorry, what is `center` variable?

Comment: i'm sorry, it should be "position", just copy-pasted wrong line.

Comment: Okey, I though, that you watching on the wrong variable :)